# Am I really wearing the Helmet and Vest in Urban Terror?

Tags: urban-terror

In Urban Terror, I always choose the Helmet and Kevlar Vest as my gear.

But I am not sure if I am actually wearing them.  When I get killed, I can see my character on the floor, and he doesn't have on a helmet and vest.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, at least with me (running 4.2 on Arch Linux x86_64). Also, you won't see any funstuff you were wearing.